# Create a MultiIndex Dataframe based on a Multindex and a dataframe (Comparison Matrix)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison, multi-index

I want to create a comparison matrix based on a dataframe df.

Let's assume the below dataframe.

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'row'   : ['a','b','c','d'],
                   'col_A' : [1,2,3,4],
                   'col_B' : [1,2,3,4],
                   'col_C' : [1,2,3,4],
                   'col_D' : [1,2,3,4]});df

 df = df.set_index('row');df
```

Dataframe looks like this:

```
     col_A  col_B  col_C  col_D
row                            
a        1      1      1      1
b        2      2      2      2
c        3      3      3      3
d        4      4      4      4
```

I also have a mapping that looks like the below, where a and b is the same entity as well as c and d.

```
mapping = pd.DataFrame({'row'   : ['a','b','c','d'],
                        'Mapping' : ['b','a','d','c']}).set_index('row');mapping
```

Therefore, I want to construct a new dataframe that has all possible combinations of the df index, but not duplicated.
I have managed to create the indexes for the new comparison dataframe with pandas MultiIndex functionality (if you can think for a more pyhtonic way please feel free to post it as well).

Creating the pandas Multi index (all possible combinations but not duplicated)

```
arrays = [['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
          ['b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'd']]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['IndexA', 'IndexB'])
```

Therefore,
Question 1: how can I construct a comparison matrix that take the absolute difference of each pair from the pandas MultiIndex and the values from the initial df.

Comparison DataFrame

```
IndexA  IndexB  Col_A   Col_B   Col_C   Col_D   
   a       b      1       1      1        1      
   a       c      2       2      2        2      
   a       d      3       3      3        3      
   b       c      1       1      1        1      
   b       d      1       1      1        1      
   c       d      1       1      1        1
```

Question 2: How can I add a new column that look up the index pair and the mapping table to define which pair is a match?

Comparison Matrix/DataFrame with a Match Column

```
    IndexA  IndexB   Col_A   Col_B  Col_C   Col_D   Match
       a       b      1       1      1        1      1
       a       c      2       2      2        2      0
       a       d      3       3      3        3      0
       b       c      1       1      1        1      0
       b       d      1       1      1        1      0
       c       d      1       1      1        1      1
```

Comment: Notice each row of original df contains same value

Comment: I see what you mean. Let me correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way for creating the new df , by using `reindex` +`get_level_values`

```
pd.DataFrame(-df.reindex(index.get_level_values(0)).values+df.reindex(index.get_level_values(1)).values,index=index,columns=df.columns)
Out[215]: 
               col_A  col_B  col_C  col_D
IndexA IndexB                            
a      b           1      1      1      1
       c           2      2      2      2
       d           3      3      3      3
b      c           1      1      1      1
       d           2      2      2      2
c      d           1      1      1      1
```

Update

```
df=pd.DataFrame(-df.reindex(index.get_level_values(0)).values+df.reindex(index.get_level_values(1)).values,index=index,columns=df.columns)

s=mapping.assign(match=1).set_index('Mapping',append=True)
pd.concat([df,s.reindex(df.index)],1).fillna(0)
Out[249]: 
               col_A  col_B  col_C  col_D  match
IndexA IndexB                                   
a      b           1      1      1      1    1.0
       c           2      2      2      2    0.0
       d           3      3      3      3    0.0
b      c           1      1      1      1    0.0
       d           2      2      2      2    0.0
c      d           1      1      1      1    1.0
```

Comment: Wen, good job mate. Any idea on how to look up based on the double indexing to bring the new column Match?

Comment: You are a star! If you can recommend any good tutorial/sources for these kind of manipulation I would much appreciat it. Thanks!

Comment: @A.Papa there are so many online tutorials in coursera , also if this is what you need can you consider accept it ?

Comment: Oh Wen, I am learning so much with you! Thanks. Answer is checked!

Comment: @A.Papa yw for us the check answer means mission complete .happy coding dude